# Extend web app hosting my sites

Tags: my-site

I have the following scenario (SP2010):

- web app 1 SharePoint - 80 hosting site collections with default zone url contoso.dummy.com
- web app 2 SharePoint - 8080 hosting my sites with default zone url contoso.dummy.com:8080

I would like keep running my sites on web app 8080 but I want users access it using a url on port 80, like for example contoso.dummy.com/social.

Is this configuration possible? Do I have to extend the web app SharePoint 8080? Can create conflict with the SharePoint - 80?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can extend you web app the way you're proposing.

You could extend the my sites web app to: my.contoso.dummy.com or social.contoso.dummy.com

It is my understanding that extending the web app only applies a secondary host url to the same content and that it does not provide a means of adding a part part to the secondary URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think you are in the right supposition. If I have available the domain my.contoso.dummy.com I could use that public url to redirect internally to contoso.dummy.com:8080. Is that what you mean?

Comment: extending a web applicaiton creates a secondary IIS site that uses the same underlying content database. This is often useful when you want to add extra authentication types to an existing instance. You could also add an Alternate Access Mapping for your existing site, wiht this you will need to add the binding to the IIS Site manually.